# Downloading XML feed to local directory using PHP

Tags: php, xml, download, xml-parsing, cron

I am  using smarty to display xml. This is the code I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source>
<publisher>SmartJobBoard</publisher>
<publisherurl><![CDATA[{$GLOBALS.site_url}]]></publisherurl>
<lastBuildDate>{$lastBuildDate}</lastBuildDate>
 {foreach from=$listings item=listing}

{if $listing.VetNetwork == '1' && $listing.Title == 'Personal Security'}

<job>
<title><![CDATA[{$listing.Title}]]></title>
<sites>
    {if $listing.VetNetwork == '1'}
    <site>veteransfeb2011</site>
    {/if}
    {if $listing.MedNetwork == '1'}
<site>hcjan2011</site>
    {/if}
    {if $listing.EdNetwork == '1'}
<site>edujul2012</site>
    {/if}   
</sites>
<date><![CDATA[{$listing.activation_date}]]></date>
<referencenumber><![CDATA[{$listing.id}]]></referencenumber>
<url><![CDATA[{$listing.listing_url}]]></url>
<company><![CDATA[{$listing.user.CompanyName}]]></company>
<city><![CDATA[{$listing.Location.City}]]></city>
<state><![CDATA[{$listing.Location.State}]]></state>
<country><![CDATA[{$listing.Location.Country}]]></country>
<postalcode><![CDATA[{$listing.Location.ZipCode}]]></postalcode>
<description><![CDATA[{$listing.JobDescription|strip_tags:false}       {$listing.JobRequirements|strip_tags:false}]]></description>
<salary><![CDATA[{$listing.Salary.value} {foreach from=$listing.SalaryType     item=list_value name="multifor"}{tr}{$list_value}{/tr}{if    !$smarty.foreach.multifor.last}, {/if}{/foreach}]]></salary>
<education><![CDATA[]]></education>
<jobtype><![CDATA[{foreach from=$listing.EmploymentType item=list_value    name="multifor"}{tr}{$list_value}{/tr}{if !$smarty.foreach.multifor.last}, {/if}   {/foreach}]]></jobtype>
<category><![CDATA[{foreach from=$listing.JobCategory item=list_value    name="multifor"}{tr}{$list_value}{/tr}{if !$smarty.foreach.multifor.last}, {/if}    {/foreach}]]></category>
<experience><![CDATA[{$listing.JobExpirience}]]></experience>
</job>
{/if}
{/foreach}
</source>
```

When you go to the URL that is linked to this template it will generate the XML in a webpage. I need to get this XML into an actual file and store it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand yet how you like to download the file with which machine to which directory. Usually the server which provides the file is responsible for the content (and it tells the client by the headers, that the content is downloadable).

With your client and your client software, you do decide to which directory the downloaded file should be stored.

You can not decide that with the content providing webserver. If that were possible, it were a security issue from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of that header stuff. To write to a "directory on the server where the PHP code resides", just use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).